# Why does the shade of colors change?

Tags: java, android, colors

I have some buttons and I want to change the background of these depending on which one was last pressed. The only problem is that the color shade changes and I don't know why.

#### Code to change the background

```
public static void swap(View on, List<View> all, int defaultColor) {
        for (View v : all) {
            Drawable backgroundOff = v.getBackground();
            backgroundOff.setTint(defaultColor);
            v.setBackground(backgroundOff);
        }
        Drawable backgroundOn = on.getBackground();
        backgroundOn.setTint(manipulateColor(defaultColor, 0.8f));
        on.setBackground(backgroundOn);
    }
```

#### Code to make default color darker

```
public static int manipulateColor(int color, float factor) {
    int a = Color.alpha(color);
    int r = Math.round(Color.red(color) * factor);
    int g = Math.round(Color.green(color) * factor);
    int b = Math.round(Color.blue(color) * factor);
    return Color.argb(a,
            Math.min(r,255),
            Math.min(g,255),
            Math.min(b,255));
}
```

#### Code of the buttons

```
final View btnTrue = (findViewById(R.id.tofTrueInput));
final View btnFalse = (findViewById(R.id.tofFalseInput));
final int defColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
final List<View> btns = new ArrayList<>();
btns.add(btnTrue);
btns.add(btnFalse);
btnTrue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        userAnswer = true;
        ExtensionMethods.swap(btnTrue, btns, defColor);
    }
});
btnFalse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        userAnswer = false;
        ExtensionMethods.swap(btnFalse, btns, defColor);
    }
});
```

#### Colors

The default color:[image: defaultColor]
The changed default color:[image: changedDefaultColor]

And the dark version of it changes likewise.

**But why?**

Comment: Could be an issue with the rounding? Or with using transparent colors (alpha channel). Maybe the `setTint` is stacking the colors or something? You could try it with non-transparent colors and see if it works then.

Comment: @user3237736 I also think that something will be with the setTint because I've already darkened a color with this code successfully. And when it resets the default color it doesn't have to manipulate the color.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it's working. I just added this line to the foreach loop:

```
backgroundOff.setTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
```

---

```
public static void swap(View on, List<View> all, int defaultColor) {
        for (View v : all) {
            Drawable backgroundOff = v.getBackground();
            backgroundOff.setTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
            backgroundOff.setTint(defaultColor);
            v.setBackground(backgroundOff);
        }
        Drawable backgroundOn = on.getBackground();
        backgroundOn.setTint(manipulateColor(defaultColor, 0.8f));
        on.setBackground(backgroundOn);
    }
```